# MySQL finding next id (next image)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've created a site for users to upload their images. However, I would like to create a next image button (or previous image button). The problem is, how can I get the "next" and "previous" id's?

The SQL structure looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `upload_time` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `upload_ip` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `warnings` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

As you see, I cannot just add a "+1" because other users may get the next id etc. Is there any good easy solution for this? Maybe an example?

I'm using codeigniter, and this is how I pull out data and views a single image

PHP

```
// Get current image by id
function get_single_image($user_id, $image_id)
{

    $this->db->where('id', $image_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('deleted', '0');

    $query = $this->db->get('images');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        $query = $query->result_array();
        return $query[0];

    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Not sure how to do using the OOP method, but the equivilant would be `WHERE id > $image_id ORDER BY id ASC` for the next image, and `WHERE id < $image_id ORDER BY id DESC` for the previous - just need someone to dress that up in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to Google CodeIgniter myself for curiosity - so here's my comment dressed up in syntax :)

Select the next image

```
$this->db->where('id >',$image_id);
$this->db->order_by('id','asc');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Select the previous image

```
$this->db->where('id <',$image_id);
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

next of the user's images: get all images with an id greater than current_id, sort ASC and take the first (with the lowest id that is still greater than current_id)

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id=? AND id>? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1", 
$user_id, $current_id
```

the same thing for previous: get all images with an id smaller then current_id, sort DESC and take the first:

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id=? AND id<? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", 
$user_id, $current_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` 
         WHERE `user_id` = ".$user_id;

$result = mysql_query( $query );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

   echo $row['id'];

}
```

This would return all of the users pic id's